# use session username to get data from mysql

Tags: php, session

I am making a profile page for a user on my site, where the person can change his/her information. I should be possible to change, name, lastname, username, code etc. But I have started with the username.

When a person log in, I store the username in session:

**index.php**

```
<?php
    if( !isset( $_SESSION['username'])) include('resources/auth/login.php');
            else exit( header('Location: home.php') );

                if( !isset( $_SESSION ) ) session_start();

    // Logout Session
    if( isset( $_GET['todo'] ) && $_GET['todo'] == 'logout'){

        session_unset();
        session_destroy();
        //echo 'You have been logged out!';
    }
?>
```

I have made a test on

**profile.php:**

```
<?php
   if( !isset( $_SESSION ) ) session_start();
?>
   <?php //echo $_SESSION['username'];?>
```

and this calls my username

But If I want to call the firstname from mysql database, that belongs to that username, should I use the `session[username]` for that? I startet to make a SQL query for it instead:

```
<?php
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT firstname FROM login");

    $stmt->execute();

    $fname = null;

      $stmt->bind_result($fname);
        while($stmt->fetch()) {
          echo $fname;
        }

    $stmt->close();
    $mysqli->close();
  ?>
```

This works, but calls all the firstnames in the database. So I tried to set the u_id, which is the PK in db = to stored session variable:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT firstname FROM login WHERE u_id=$username");
```

and

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT firstname FROM loginWHERE u_id = '.$_SESSION[username]'";
```

But here I get an error: 
*Undefined variable: username in profile.php*

Can anybody see why that is?

Comment: you start the session **AFTER** trying to access/use a $_SESSION value? that makes no sense. PHP can't time travel, and won't retroactively re-run the username test after calling session_start(). and note that testing for a `set` session isn't a valid test for session_start(). it's entirely possible to have a session (which is really just a cookie) without having a $_SESSION at all. use `session_status()` instead.

Comment: I cannot see I start the session after? It is the first script there is running when a person log in.

Comment: if you don't call `session_start()`, then `$_SESSION` is a blank/empty array, meaning you'll never be able to find a username in there.

Comment: Sorry I can see I am missing some informations in my question. I will just update it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i understand you well,i think this query:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT firstname FROM login WHERE u_id=$username");
```

should be this:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT firstname FROM login WHERE username ='.$_SESSION[username].'");
//forgive my syntax issues
```

if you want to retrieve the firstname of a user that is logged, the parameter for the where clause should be the the user's username as that is the only unique way to identify the user, however may i suggest you also set the id of the user in a session too, so that the where parameter now takes the user's unique id. Its a better way of making sure you retrieve information for that particular user, because two users may have the same username, so when your where clause takes that as a parameter, it retrieves two rows from the database, that will definitely cause problems.

Comment: Thank you a lot, the username is called now. I will check out the id aswell. In my questin I also asked about calling the firstname on that specifk user. Do I have to use the session[username] for that, or how could I do that?

Comment: On the profile page where you want to display the details, run a query like this:  select * from login where username = $_SESSION[username], then use a loop to display whatever you want to..do you understand what i mean?

Comment: I did not think of that. I understand what you mean, but I have to see into how I can make that. I am in doubt of how I get the column names from the database. But I can do it in a while loop?

Comment: ahh yes. SELECT * FROM etc from that specifik user with the username/id. So I get this `Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_result(): Number of bind variables doesn't match number of fields in prepared statement in`: , which means that I have to bind the x variables there is in my database, right?

Comment: Yeah..you welcome, sorry i wasn't able to answer your other questions, i stepped out, glad you got it working..

Answer (score 1):

It is high propable that you didn't start the session. I only know the writing $_SESSION['username'] instead of u_id = ' . $_SESSION[username]'

Comment: Thank you a lot. Works with the username now